# Looping videos in PsychoPy

Tags: video, psychopy

I'm using PsychoPy v.1.82.01 on OS X v10.10.5, in the coder view. I want to play a video and loop it (play it repeatedly) until the participant has pressed the right arrow key. The problem is that my video does not loop and PsychoPy freezes unless the right arrow key is pressed immediately after the video has finished playing. The same code works fine on a Windows PC - the video loops until the right arrow key is pressed.

```
    def single_trial(video, win):
        current_video = visual.MovieStim(win, filename = log_dir + '/' + str(video), flipVert=False, loop = True) 
        event.clearEvents('keyboard')
        received_press = False
        while not (received_press):
            arrow_list = event.getKeys(keyList = ['right'])
            for arrow in arrow_list:
                if arrow == 'right':
                    received_press = True
            current_video.draw()
            win.flip()
```

I have not used videos before in PsychoPy, but I have used the same code with images.

Comment: Given that it works on Windows, the problem presumably isn't with your code. There have been a lot of changes by PsychoPy recently to use alternative underlying movie playing libraries. The version you are using is nearly a year old: check the change log here to see that from a movie-playing point of view, it would definitely be worth upgrading: http://www.psychopy.org/changelog.html